# How can I add onPress here

Tags: react-native

```
const SECTIONS = [
{
header: 'Персональные настройки',
icon: 'settings',
items: [
{ icon: 'globe', color: '#fe9400', label: 'Язык  ', type: 'link', onPress:()=>setModalVisible(true)},
{icon: 'moon',color: '#007afe',label: 'Темная тема  ',value: false,type: 'boolean'},
{icon: 'bell',color: '#800080',label: 'Уведомления  ',value: false,type: 'boolean'},
{ icon: 'lock', color: '#32c759', label: 'Изменить пароль ', type: 'link' },
{ icon: 'user', color: 'red', label: 'Удалить аккаунт ', type: 'link' }
],
},
];
```

I have Settings Screen of my app and I have array. I don't know how to add onPress in it and make it work?